# Help with notation for $\mathbb C\rightarrow \mathbb C$ and $\mathbb R^2\rightarrow\mathbb C$

Tags: complex-analysis

*Question 1:*

For a complex function $f:\mathbb C\rightarrow \mathbb C$ are the following notations equivalent?
\begin{align}
f(z)&=u(z)+iv(z) \tag 1\\
f(z)&=u(x,y)+iv(x,y)\tag 2\\
f(x+iy)&=u(x+iy)+iv(x+iy)\tag 3\\
f(x,y)&=u(x,y)+iv(x,y) \tag 4
\end{align}

*Question 2:*

Say I have a function $g:\mathbb R^2\rightarrow \mathbb C$, i.e.
$$
g(x,y)=u(x,y)+iv(x,y)\tag 5
$$

The domain is now real, but the notation is the same as $(4)$?

Is my notation of $f$ or $g$ wrong?

Update: Clarified the questions.

Answer (score 1):

I have never seen $(1)$, $(2)$ or $(3)$. On the other hand, $(4)$ is very common.

If you consider $f(z)=z^3$, and if $x,y\in\mathbb R$, then$$\tag{A}f(x+yi)=x^3-3xy^2+(3x^2y-y^3)i$$and so, in this case, you have$$u(x,y)=x^3-3xy^2\text{ and }v(x,y)=3x^2y-y^3.$$However, working with $z^3$ is simpler and more natural than working with $(\mathrm A)$.

On the other hand, since $\mathbb{C}=\mathbb{R}^2$, there is no question of different domains here.

Comment: Hi! I just updated the question, so the numbering is different now.

Comment: Don't you mean $(2)$ is common? I guess that notation is used in your example?

Comment: @JDoeDoe In my example?! Where did I write such a nonsense?

Answer (score 0):

$(1)=(3)$.

$(1)$ is not applicable, we write $z=x+iy$ so again we have $i$ in $u(z)$ and $v(z)$. Commonly $u(x,y)$ and $v(x,y)$ are real two variables functions.

In general $f(p)=q$ where $f:\mathbb{R}^m\to\mathbb{R}^n$ is a map on ordered sets then $f(p)=f((x,y))=f(x,y)$ refers to ordered pair and isn't the same as $f(z)$ for $z\in\mathbb{C}$. So $(2)$ is correct notation rather than $(4)$ as **bad** spelling.